# TinyMCE remove DIVs when pasting in the editor - how?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

TinyMCE - when you copy and paste in TinyMCE the past is wrapped around DIV tags. Anyone know how to disable that? I don't see the need for DIV tags, so I'm not sure why TINYMCE adds them? And there is no mention in the docs.

Thanks

[http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/paste](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aPlugins/paste)

Answer (score 1):

Usually, all textual content is wraped inside paragraphs - not divs.

Are you talking about additional divs inside paragraphs?
In that case you might be able to use paste_preprocess to cut it off yourself.
A second option could be to use the paste_postprocess option to remove it.

Comment: If you load an instance of TinyMCE, type stuff, then copy it and paste it inside of TinyMCE, the entire paste is wrapped inside a DIV. that's what I'm trying to prevent from happening. thoughts?

Comment: hmm, i am not able to reproduce the behavior you describe, can you please post your full tinymce configuration and explicitly show how pasted text gets wrapped (eachstep described, output of firebufg would be helpfull)

Comment: I'm actually having the exact same problem ... and just realized this was a year ago not a few days ago. Going to play with the paste_postprocess however. But the OP is correct: When selecting the entire contents of a TinyMCE editor, and pasting it into a new TinyMCE editor you find the entirety wrapped with an extra div which maps to the ID you have put on the editor. Really annoying.

Comment: in that case someone should file a bugreport at www.tinymce.com